# How to get terser webpack plugin works properly

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am trying to understand how to get [terser webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) to work in the most simple possible case.

This is my code:

`src/math.js`, exports 2 functions.

```
export const double = (x) =>
  x + x;

export const triple = (x) =>
  x + x + x;
```

`scr/index.js`, imports only `double` function.

```
import { double } from './math.js';
console.log(double(10));
```

I understood from [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) that I must use `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` if I want activate tree shaking. 
[image: webpack doc]

This is my webpack config:

`webpack/index.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    ['@babel/preset-env', {
                        modules: false
                    }]
                ],
                babelrc: false
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
  ],
  optimization: {
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({})],
  }
};
```

I don't understand what I missed in my webpack config. The webpack output is without minification or tree shaking...

---

node: "v10.10.0"

webpack: "^4.28.1"

webpack-cli: "^3.2.1"

@babel/core: "^7.2.2"

@babel/preset-env: "^7.1.5"

babel-loader: "^8.0.5"

terser-webpack-plugin: "^1.2.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you have `mode` set to `none`, `optimization.minimize` is set to `false`, so your custom instance of Terser is never instantiated.

Add `minimize: true` to the `optimization` object and it should work.