# How to minify with TerserPlugin and webpack-encore

Tags: symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore, terser

With this webpack.config.js that use webpack-encore, and minify with terser, I can compile successfully, but absolutely nothing is minified at all. Comments, and full variable names, are still there.

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableReactPreset()
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableLessLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

     .addEntry('app_prescription', [
         './assets/js/prescription/app_prescription.js'
     ])



    .addLoader({
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader?cacheDirectory"
    })

;


if( Encore.isProduction() ) {
    Encore.addPlugin(new TerserPlugin({parallel: true,cache:true}) );
}

module.exports = function(env) {

    Encore.enableVersioning();
    const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig() ;

    if( Encore.isProduction() ) {

        config.optimization = {
            minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({parallel: true,cache:true})]
        }
    }



    return config ;
}
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get terser webpack plugin works properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131749/how-to-get-terser-webpack-plugin-works-properly)

Comment: Not specific to encore. "config.optimization.minimize : true" is missing .

Answer (score 4):

Late answer for everyone who stumbles upon this in 2021 and later:

Use encore's [`configureTerserPlugin`](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/f5a17a47b5fcd23ff991bd7154385185c7f54e2f/index.js#L168-L183) method:

```js
 Encore.configureTerserPlugin((options) => {
     options.cache = true;
     options.terserOptions = {
         output: {
             comments: false
         }
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#extractcomments to avoid generating `*.LICENSE.txt` files you should use this option of method:

```
Encore.configureTerserPlugin(options => {
    options.extractComments = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

Encore.configureTerserPlugin((options) => {
    options.extractComments = false;
    options.terserOptions = {
        output: {
            comments: false,
        },
    };
});

// Minify code
const optimization = {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin(),
    ],
}

... // other encore code in here

module.exports = {
    ...Encore.getWebpackConfig(),
    name: config.name,
    optimization,
};
```